# Run 32 bit python script in a 64 bit program

Tags: python, ms-access, odbc, pyodbc, pyside6

I am having an issue with my current program. I have a GUI program I made using pyside6 (using python 64bit). The program needs to write data to a Microsoft Access Database that is stored on a network drive. This is where I run into problems. In order to make a connection using ODBC I need that python file (the one that writes the data to the database) to be ran using python 32 bit. This is because the ODBC drivers I need are only installed in my 32 bit version, and I can't seem to get them on my 64 bit OBDC version. (I have tried installing access data management engine but it errors out since I have both 32 and 64 bit versions of office on my machine)

Is there a way to tell the python file that writes the data, lets call it Access.py, to always use a different interpreter than other python files. If so, can I still import Access.py and use the writeData() function in my 64 bit pyside6 program. I am using visual studio code if that helps. Below are examples of my code:

32 bit Access.py program:

```
import pyodbc
#32 bit python program
def WriteData(mailFrom,mailTo,mailSubject,mailMessage,format):
    # Connect to the database
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=\\strvltstorage.av.ge.com\st001dataaege\siteapps\WINAPPS\SendMail\SendMail.mdb;')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Example data to insert into the table
    new_entry = (mailFrom,mailTo,mailSubject,mailMessage,format)

    # Execute the INSERT INTO statement
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MailTable (Mail_From, Mail_To, Mail_Subject, Mail_Body, Mail_Format) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", new_entry)

    # Commit the transaction
    conn.commit()

    # Close the connection
    conn.close()

    print("Data entry added successfully.")
```

The above code must be ran using a 32 bit compiler in order to access the .mdb driver, but I need to call the function from a 64 bit pyside6 program. (From what I understand, pyside6 doesn't work in 32 bit.)

Here is an example of a pyside6 program. I didn't want to post the actual one since it's multiple files and several thousand lines of code
Pyside6 Program:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
import sys
import Access #32 bit program

class HelloWorldApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create a central widget and set the layout
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        # Create a button
        self.button = QPushButton('Click me!', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.writeData)

        # Add the button to the layout
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def writeData(self):
        Access.WriteData('it.strother@domain.com', 'luke@domain.com', 'From Python','Sending from python','text') #Calling 32 bit function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create and show the main window
    main_window = HelloWorldApp()
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The first thing I tried was getting Access.py to run on 64 bit, but I can't figure out how to install the .mdb drivers for the 64 bit ODBC. Everywhere online points to installing the Access Database engine, but when I install the 32 bit or 64 bit version I get an error saying it detects 64 bit or 32 bit office products installed.
[64 bit drivers vs 32 bit drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFjoe.png)

This software will eventually be pushed out to several machines that will all have the same windows installation that I have, so I don't want to remove programs/edit registries.

Comment: if you are using different interpreters, then they would be in separate processes.

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning, what do you mean by separate processes. Does that mean I can' call the function from my other file? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: x32 bit software can't call or directly use x64 bit software. And the reverse is also true. So, any kind of "in process" use of a library requires that such software and their library code runs as the same bit size. Industry been that way since the dawn of computers. So, either you install the x64 bit access data engine. There are notes that you can use the /quiet open to install the x64 data engine even when using office x32. So, if your software is running as x64 bits, then you need x64 bit versions of the ODBC - you have little or not choice in this matter.